# Issue regarding flutter-slider (errors_patch.dart -> AssertionError_throwNew error)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-widget

I'm fairly new to Flutter, and I was trying to implement a horizontal-slider with divisions using the external *syncfusion_flutter_sliders* library.
Here's my attempt at the implementation:

```
class SliderExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliderExample({super.key});
  @override
  State<SliderExample> createState() => _SliderExampleState();
}

class _SliderExampleState extends State<SliderExample> {
  final double _min = 0;
  final double _max = 100;
  double _value = 40.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SfSlider(
          min: _min,
          max: _max,
          value: _value,
          interval: 20,
          showTicks: true,
          showLabels: true,
          onChanged: (dynamic newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _value = newValue;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The above stateful widget when called in another stateless route, throws the following error:

**ERROR -> errors_patch.dart**

```
@pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNew")
external static _doThrowNew(
    int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message);
```

**CALL**

```
return Scaffold(
  body:
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.orangeAccent, Colors.deepOrange]),
      ),
      child: ListView(
        children: const <Widget>[
          Text('\n\n\nHow Many People Did You Meet Today?',
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
          ),
          MaterialApp(
            home: SliderExample(), // <-- HERE
          )
        ]
      ),
  ),
);
```

Resources to the flutter library followed: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders ;p.s. Excuse me if it's an elementary fix, in view of the fact that I'm trying to learn by making an app from scratch using the Flutter Docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this part of your code to this

```
child: ListView(
        children: const <Widget>[
          Text('\n\n\nHow Many People Did You Meet Today?',
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
          ),
          SliderExample(),
        ]
      ),
```

You shouldn't call `MaterialApp(home: )` there.

And in `_SliderExampleState`, change the following part to the one below

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SfSlider(
    min: _min,
    max: _max,
    value: _value,
    interval: 20,
    showTicks: true,
    showLabels: true,
    onChanged: (dynamic newValue) {
      setState(() {
        _value = newValue;
      });
    },
  );
}
```

Remove the wrapping in `Scaffold` and `Center`.

Comment: The error still persists, although it's a different one this time around...
**ERROR: (box.dart):**
`throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[DiagnosticsProperty<BoxConstraints>('The constraints that applied to the $runtimeType were', constraints, style: DiagnosticsTreeStyle.errorProperty), DiagnosticsProperty<Size>('The exact size it was given was', _size, style: DiagnosticsTreeStyle.errorProperty),`

Comment: **Resource:** https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints

Comment: Edited, give a try.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot :)
Actually could you point me to some resources regarding why this error could've happened, if any?